# Подключать пользовательский код к своему

Tags: c#, компиляция

Интересует такой вопрос: возможно ли подключать пользовательский код к своему обрабатывать и получать ответ. Если проще сказать... допустим у меня этот код:

```cs
using System;

namespace Script
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi user! Enter your code to continue");
            string Code = Console.ReadLine();
            ...
            try
            {

            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Когда программа доходит до строки `string Code = Console.ReadLine();` пользователь пишет там свой код.
Например:

```cs
int a = 3;
int b = 5;

a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;

Console.WriteLine($"{a}/{b}");
```

---

*Теперь как компилировать этот код и проверять с помощью `try`?*

---

Я пытался найти стати по поводу этого, но не получилось. Так что можете как ответ оставить ссылку на статью (желательно русскоязычную).

Comment: Вам нужно будет генерировать полноценный файл с кодом, вставив туда введённый фрагмент. Потом запустить команды на компиляцию и выполнение исполняемого файла. Но тут нужно действовать очень аккуратно, потому что если вы будете выполнять любой код, который введёт пользователь, то этот код может оказаться вредоносным.

Comment: Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону чего-то вроде [ejudge](https://ejudge.ru/wiki/index.php/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_ejudge)

Comment: @КириллМалышев Я слышал просто про библиотеку `System.CodeDom.Compiler` с ним пару примеров я нашёл в StackOverflow но они считались устаревшими и не работают. К тому же эту библиотеку вроде переместили. Я думал может есть похожие библиотеки с которым можно совершить такое или хотя бы с `CodeDom`-ом может всё ещё такое возможно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Согласен :-)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это именно то что я искал